# Use of underscore with color variable in mathplotlib horizontal bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, rgb

I'm working my way through a horizontal bar chart [code example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html) in mathplotlib.
Since I'm new to Python, I'm struggling to understand the use of underscore in this line:

```
r, g, b, _ = color
```

I have looked at multiple resources explaining the use of underscore in Python, however, I'm still not sure about this particular case.
Can someone help me out and point me in the right direction?

Comment: An underscore is traditionally used in Python when variable unpacking requires a certain number of parameters but one or more will not be used in the following code. See 3) in the first answer: [What is the purpose of the single underscore "\_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)

Comment: One. Not "one or more". Otherwise, it would be `r, g, b, *_ = color`.